# What are the "Boeing Lunar Orbiter spacecraft" from the 1960s? Why is "Boeing" in the name?

Tags: the-moon, photography, mapping, lunar-orbit, boeing

An October 2013 article in SpaceRef.com [The New Race for the Moon](http://spaceref.com/asia/the-new-race-for-the-moon.html) says:

> Although LRO data remains unrestricted there is other evidence that NASA is worried about such data transfer to China.
>
> NASA recently removed at least four major photographic atlases of the Moon from the NASA Technical Reports Server. The large volumes document the thousands of images taken by Boeing Lunar Orbiter spacecraft in the 1960s to map the Moon at close range to find Apollo landing sites and to gain a better understanding of the body.

**Question:** What are "Boeing Lunar Orbiter spacecraft in the 1960s" Did Boeing have its own spacecraft? Did it contract for someone else to launch them?

Could this just be referring to the plain old "Lunar Orbiters" that mapped the Moon, and who's data is readily available today? For example like I accessed here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31310/12102 If so, why might they be referred to as "Boeing Lunar Orbiters"?

Comment: I've also just asked [Did NASA remove four major photographic atlases of the Moon from its Technical Report Server? Gone for good, or just hype?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32626/12102)

Comment: Boeing, despite being best known for airplanes, still makes communication satellites today; the one that still bemuses me is that [Chrysler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler) built the [Saturn I/IB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_IB) first stage.

Comment: Boeing also built most of the US side of the ISS. https://www.boeing.com/history/products/international-space-station.page  As far as Chrysler goes, NASA in the Space Age knew that auto companies were leading engineering organizations and drew on their expertise; Ford built the Mission Control Center.  http://ophelia.sdsu.edu:8080/ford/01-24-2009/about-ford/heritage/milestones/nasamissioncontrol/683-nasa-mission-control.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble there's a question here somewhere, I can't figure out how to word it yet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's referring to the plain old [Lunar Orbiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbiter_program) of the 1960s. Boeing manufactured the spacecraft for NASA.

According to NASA's [Destination Moon: A History of the Lunar Orbiter Program](https://history.nasa.gov/TM-3487/contents.htm), Boeing (in collaboration with Eastman Kodak) was one of 5 companies that responded to NASA's call for proposals, and the one that was ultimately chosen for the project.